# What happens to a character whose load exceeds maximum?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, encumbrance

Rules give us 3 value ranges for load: Light, Medium and Heavy.

There are respective bonuses/penalties to those loads. I couldn't find any mention of what happens after exceeding heavy load range (endpoint is named maximum load).

Can such character even move? Does such character get damaged by being smashed to the ground by his/her own equipment?

Also - what happens to creatures that are extremely heavy on their own (let's say dragons) when their strength drops to very low levels? I can't believe that such dragon would be able to move if it had strength of a regular human.

Answer (score 2):

From the "Carrying Capacity" section of the rules, specifically the section on "Lifting and Dragging" (emphasis mine):

> Lifting and Dragging: A character can lift as much as his maximum load over his head. A character’s maximum load is the highest amount of weight listed for a character’s Strength in the heavy load column of Table: Carrying Capacity.
>
> *A character can lift as much as double his maximum load off the ground,* but he or she can only stagger around with it. **While overloaded in this way, the character loses any Dexterity bonus to AC and can move only 5 feet per round (as a full-round action).**
>
> *A character can generally push or drag along the ground as much as five times his maximum load.* Favorable conditions can double these numbers, and bad circumstances can reduce them by half or more.

I have not seen any specific rules for what happens if a creature becomes so weak they can no longer support their own body weight. RAW, they would need a Strength score of 0 before this would happen (and they would become unconscious).

See the [Pathfinder SRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/) for a table that describes low strength scores. The only one that mentions a penalty to movement is a Strength score of zero (and that is because you would be unconscious).

I have not seen any rules on equipment crushing a character as they become too weak to carry it.

Comment: All of what You're quoting here provides information on "what are the limits" (which I stated I already know) and doesn't help in any way in answering "what happens beyond those limits". There are lots of spells/curses/abilities that reduce strength so having Your armor suddenly heavier than what You can carry is a real and quite common usecase.

Comment: @NecXelos You said you did not know what happened beyond Maximum Load. I just showed you. You can stumble around until twice Maximum load. You can push/drag until 5x Maximum load. You can move 5 ft. per round as a full-round action. You lose your Dex bonus to AC. It is all spelled out in that text block. Beyond that, you are stuck in place.

Comment: https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/ see the table in Strength section. It'll help you to turn this into a full answer.

Comment: I've had GM's *homerule* damage for the crushing weight of things when a character (or enemy) has their strength sapped while holding something particularly heavy (an instance with a portcullis comes to mind). But I believe this is correct by the book.

Comment: Can You elaborate ifusaso?

Comment: Intersterllar Probe, what You're talking about are different types of activities. You can't suddenly drop the plate armor You're wearing when You loose Your strength so neither push/drag nor pick up pretend it's barbells really applies here.

Comment: @NecXelos Please update your question. It is becoming clear that you are not looking for published rules, but you would like house rules. I have provided the published references. You clearly disagree that they cover the situations you are inquiring about. Please be specific why you feel these rules do not satisfy the situations you describe.

Comment: I would actually prefer official rules OR official errata OR official public statement from Paizo employee OR whetever other official source can there be. I refuse to believe that such a hole in rules was left behind in so many years. I'll wait few more days, maybe someone with better access finds something.

Comment: @NecXelos I have a feeling you will find better assistance if you update your question to include why you feel the existing rules are inadequate. Pathfinder uses abstractions. In real life, combat is not turn-based. In real life, people do not have strength scores at all. But, you are not bothered by that. You are bothered by the abstraction that you can move normally while carrying up to your maximum load, but up to twice your maximum load, you are limited to 5 feet as a full-round action. Please update your question to describe what this is insufficient.

Comment: In general, it is difficult to address a question you do not ask.